# Using python and regex to remove repeated character strings within a word

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, duplicates

I'm using `pandas` in `python` to clean and prepare some data by sorting words in a string alphabetically and removing repeated character strings within a word

i.e. `"informative text about texting"` would become `"about informative ing text"`

My attempt (below) sorts the words alphabetically and removes duplicate words, but does not remove duplicate words with additional characters either side.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'raw':['informative text about texting','some more text text']})
df['cleaned'] = df['raw'].str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())).str.join(' ')
df.to_dict()
>>> {'raw': {0: 'informative text about texting', 1: 'some more text text'},
     'cleaned': {0: 'about informative text texting', 1: 'more some text'}}
```

Is there a way to do this using `regex`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it about 2 words, with at least 3 chars? https://regex101.com/r/3d4gTc/1

Comment: @FourthBird, cool solution but I'm afraid isn't general enough. I'm trying to identify the character string(s) that is(are) repeated (either as a word or within a word) and remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is a way to do this using regex, but it may not entirely be necessary. One may opt for something like this:

```
string = "informative text about texting"
new_string = string.replace("text", "").replace("  ", " ")
```

Above, we replace `"text"` with nothing and then replace a double space with a single space. We need to replace double spaces because when a string contains `"text"` with a space on either side, it will remove `"text"` and leave two spaces.

Using regex:

```
string = "informative text about texting"
new_string = re.sub(r"\stext|text", "", string)
```

This regex looks for a space that precedes `"text"` (`\stext`) and then uses the `|` as an or operator followed by `text` to also match just `"text"`.

### Edit

Let's take two examples:

```
"foo bar baz bar"
"foo bar baz barr"
```

If given the first string, the output should be `"foo bar baz"` and if given the second string, the output should be `"foo bar baz r"`

So, how can we accomplish this? Firstly, we need to consider how we can remove duplicates in a string. In this example, I use `set` to do this. To remove basic duplicates like `"bar bar"` (not complex duplicates like `"bar barr"`):

```
unique = set(string.split())
```

Then, we can join `unique` using `join` so that we are able to regex it , like so:

```
new = " ".join(unique)
```

Then, we can loop through each word in `unique` and regex the entire string with each word so that we can remove the complex duplicates I mentioned above:

```
for word in unique:
    pattern = fr"({word}(?=[^\s]))|((?<=[^\s]){word})"
    new = re.sub(pattern, "", new)
```

Now, the entire script should look like this:

```
unique = set(string.split())
new = " ".join(unique)
for word in unique:
    pattern = fr"({word}(?=[^\s]))|((?<=[^\s]){word})"
    new = re.sub(pattern, "", new)
```

### Regex Explanation

```
({word}(?=[^\s]))|((?<=[^\s]){word})
```

This regex uses both a lookahead and lookbehind. You can ask yourself this question: what criteria has to be met for the string of characters to be replaced. Well, a word is separated by spaces. So, using the lookahead, we can look for strings of characters that do not precede a space:

```
({word}](?=[^\s]))
```

The `[^\s]` matches characters that are not a space. We can then use the lookbehind in the same manner so that the regex matches the strings of characters that do not follow a space:

```
((?<=[^\s]){word})
```

We then join them with the `or` operator (`\`) to complete the pattern:

```
({word}(?=[^\s]))|((?<=[^\s]){word})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, I don't know that the word `"text"` is the repeating set of characters (it was just an example); is there a way of identifying the repeating characters first and then using `str.replace`?

Comment: @SamShort gotcha. So, let's say the string is `"foo bar baz bar"`. Because `"bar"` appears more than once, you would then want to remove the duplicate instances of `"bar"`?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. Your example is much better. There is an additional complexity though, if the string is `foo bar baz barr` I also want to remove `bar`. I could live with the result being either `foo bar baz r` or `foo bar baz`

Comment: @SamShort thanks for the clarification! I will work on an updated answer!

Comment: Thanks so much, @gmdev!

Comment: @SamShort see my edit, this should get you up and running. I am experimenting with other regex patterns to see if there is a simpler one, but the existing one will work as-is.

Comment: Thanks @gmdev. Looks great! Let me know if you find a regex solution? I'm trying to avoid using the `apply` functionality in `pandas` - it's super slow.

Comment: @SamShort I personally could not find a simpler solution for this; however, I did add a regex explanation so that it is more understandable

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It's really helpful - regex is hard!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help! Regex is tough to write when learning but it is usually much tougher to read someone else's regex pattern, LOL.